# No Unallocated Space Visible After Shrinking Partition (GParted)

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, gparted, swap

I know there are a *lot* of questions concerning resizing partitions with GParted, but none of them seem to address the problem I'm having.

I have two hard drives, one of which is a 2 TB HDD attached via SATA. There already exists an ext4 partition on this drive, which uses all of the drive's space, and has used ~500 GB of space. I want to shrink this partition to free up 32 GiB of space to create a swap partition.

I'm having some issues in doing this with GParted, both while running the application within Ubuntu, and while using the live-USB. The drive is unmounted. I right click on the drive, and choose "Resize/Move". I then change the free space following (MiB) to be 32768 MiB (=32 GiB), as shown in the image linked here:

[Resizing the partition to add 32 GiB of space following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeOks.png)

This left the [planned changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZLyS.png) as the `/dev/sda` partition occupying 1.79 TiB, followed by 32.00 GiB of unallocated space. When I applied the changes using the tick, the operation completed successfully (unfortunately, I didn't save the log from this run). However, when I pressed "close" on the window saying the change was successful, the unallocated space disappeared from the view in GParted, and the size of the original partition was shown as 1.82 TiB (not the 1.79 TiB it should have been following the change).

Trying to resize the partition again, the operation completed successfully, however looking through details, I saw that for the "shrink filesystem" operation, `resize2fs` (version 1.45.5) outputted "The filesystem is already 479990016 (4k) blocks long. Nothing to do!". The operation completed far quicker than the previous resize, so I assume the previous one did actually resize the partition, but somehow the partition table wasn't updated? Once I pressed "close", once again, GParted showed [none of the expected changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivVbC.png).

I've experienced the same issues trying to run GParted on a live USB as in the application.

I'm not massively concerned about any of the data on there, so it's not a big deal if it's all lost or something, but it would be inconvenient to have to rebuild everything. It's still possible to mount the drive, and files are all still readable.

I've included the [log GParted generated](https://pastebin.com/7TwiRueY) in the latter run in case that's helpful at all. I'd greatly appreciate any advice on how to solve this! I'm happy to provide any more information that's necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sda` is not a partition but the whole device, your disk does not have a partition table as you can see in line 28 in the log you provided. You can't resize `sda`, since it's not a partition and no partition table entries exist.

Your disk is set up to hold only a single file-system which you successfully resized, but there is no way to make use of the space you made.

You'll need  to backup your data, create a partition table and the partitions you want to have. Then restore your data from backup to the new partition.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! That makes total sense, I just wasn't actually aware it was possible to create a disk with no partition table. Have a great day :D

Comment: @user14749127 Yes, it's possible, see also [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/276582/590937)